# left side navbar with affix.js and flexible with screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to have a navbar on the left which is fixed when scrolling, but is flexible with the size of the screen. I used the following

```
    <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar" role="navigation" data-spy="affix" style="width: 180px;">
            <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
```

with data-spy="affix" I make sure that the navbar is fixed. However, since I included affix I have an annoying effect when I load the site. First the text on the site appears low (about 300px below where it is supposed to be)... and than it goes to the place where I want it. I think the reason is that it takes time to load the affix.js file and only after loading it does it put the text at the right place. My question therefore is how can I avoid this?

Maybe affix is a bit too much, since it is actually used to have a navbar which is dynamic. I don't really want that. I guess I could try to get the navbar without a javascript, but that seemed a bit tricky. My navbar is flexible with screen size, and I can't figure out how to make it additionally to that fixed against scrolling.

hi again: it took me a while to figure out how jsfiddle works, but here is the link

https://jsfiddle.net/carl101/rb8x80yb/2/embedded/result/

it shows the navbar on the left and the navbar on the top. So basically everything is working. The problem is that if the content is big, the site has the problem described above

https://jsfiddle.net/carl101/rb8x80yb/2/

Comment: Can you be a bit clear and show your full code on a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear about what you say. As far as I can understand, you would need a fixed sidebar, that doesn't scroll with a header too. Right? Does this solution work for you?

```css
/* Start Praveen's Reset for Fiddle ;) */
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI'; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}
/* End Praveen's Reset for Fiddle ;) */
a {text-decoration: none;}

html, body {height: 100%;}
body {padding-top: 50px; padding-left: 75px;}
p {margin: 0 0 10px;}

header {background-color: #000; position: fixed; top: 0; width: 100%; z-index: 2; left: 0;}
header h1 {line-height: 1; text-align: center; padding: 5px 0; font-weight: 1.5em;}
header h1 a {font-weight: normal; color: #fff;}

aside {position: fixed; left: 0; height: 100%; top: 30px; background-color: #99f; padding-top: 25px; z-index: 1; width: 70px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <h1><a href="">Heading</a></h1>
</header>
<aside>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Item 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Item 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</aside>
<p>Jason John Gesser (born May 31, 1979) is an American college football coach and former player, currently the quarterbacks coach for the Wyoming Cowboys of the Mountain West Conference.</p>
<p>He was previously the interim head coach, offensive coordinator, quarterbacks coach, and recruiting coordinator for the Idaho Vandals of the WAC. He played quarterback for Washington State Cougars of the Pac-10 under head coach Mike Price, and played in the 2003 Rose Bowl. As a professional, Gesser played for the Utah Blaze of the Arena Football League, the Calgary Stampeders of the Canadian Football League, and the Tennessee Titans of the National Football League. He was originally hired at Idaho as running backs coach in June 2011. Gesser is the grandson of Green Bay Packers Hall of Fame member Joseph "Red" Dunn.</p>
<p>Jason John Gesser (born May 31, 1979) is an American college football coach and former player, currently the quarterbacks coach for the Wyoming Cowboys of the Mountain West Conference.</p>
<p>He was previously the interim head coach, offensive coordinator, quarterbacks coach, and recruiting coordinator for the Idaho Vandals of the WAC. He played quarterback for Washington State Cougars of the Pac-10 under head coach Mike Price, and played in the 2003 Rose Bowl. As a professional, Gesser played for the Utah Blaze of the Arena Football League, the Calgary Stampeders of the Canadian Football League, and the Tennessee Titans of the National Football League. He was originally hired at Idaho as running backs coach in June 2011. Gesser is the grandson of Green Bay Packers Hall of Fame member Joseph "Red" Dunn.</p>
```

Comment: hi Praveen... thanks for your answer. This is not quite what I need since I want the left navbar to be aligned with the top navbar. See the fiddle I added above

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out... {position: fixed} does the job without the need for affix.js... thanks for your patience with me
best
carl